# Changing OnMouseOut event from within JavaScript only works momentarily

Tags: javascript, html, image

a quick question here,
I am attempting to change the source of an image for the OnMouseOut event from within JavaScript

The image changes just fine, but only works until I attempt to reenter the element after which the tag seems to get lost...

Here's the image/button code:

```
<img id="ImageBTN" src="image1_relative_path" onclick="Afunction()" onmouseover="src='image2_relative_path'" onmouseout="src='image1_relative_path'"/>
```

The image/button like that works like a charm and switches between Image 1 and Image 2 with respect to our mouse movement.
Now I would like to change the image when clicking on it in such a way that Image 1 is basically substituted by Image 3

Here's the JavaScript code

```
function Afunction()
        {
            document.getElementById('ImageBTN').src = "image3_relative_path";
            document.getElementById('ImageBTN').onmouseout = "src='image3_relative_path'";
        }
```

Like I said above, the code works, until I attempt to reenter the object. Here's how this goes:

- The page loads and Image 1 is displayed
- I hover my mouse over the image and the image is changed to Image 2
- Upon leaving the image Image 1 is restored
- Again returning to the object Image 2 is shown
- Clicking the object (I assume the change of SRC does this) the image is changed to Image 3
- Leaving the object keeps the display of Image 3 (Assuming onmouseout does this)
- Upon reentry of the object once again, correctly Image 2
- Now after leaving the object or doing whatever, only Image 2 is ever shown

It is as if the src and onmouseout tags got deleted after being used (After the mouse has left the object)

I'd very much appreciate some insight!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use for `onclick` the same logic you used for the other 2 events. I hope this is what you need.

```html
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" 
     onclick="src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/puppyD300.jpg'"
     onmouseout="src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg'" 
     onmouseover="src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/puppyBeagle300.jpg'" width="300" height="300"/>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying... Yes I am doing the same by calling _Afunction()_ from my _onclick_ tag, it does not work as intended.

The way I will go about solving this issue is by having another image in place of the first one and then alternating between them using the _display_ tag

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot accept your answer as it doesn't solve the issue